# PHP display array value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm beginner to php. I've following array. I'm trying to print my array as 07:30:00 to 08:20:00, 08:20:00 to 09:10:00, 09:10:00 to 10:00:00 and so on. Thanks in advance

```
  Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 1 [time] => 07:30:00 ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 2 [time] => 08:20:00 ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 3 [time] => 09:10:00 ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 4 [time] => 10:00:00 ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 5 [time] => 10:50:00 ) 
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 6 [time] => 11:40:00 ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 7 [time] => 12:30:00 ) 
    [7] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 8 [time] => 13:20:00 ) 
    [8] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 9 [time] => 14:05:00 ) 
    [9] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 10 [time] => 14:50:00 ) 
    [10] => stdClass Object ( [time_id] => 11 [time] => 01:00:00 ) 

)
```

I've used this code

```
    <?php foreach ($time as $t) {


                        echo "<tr >";
                        echo "<td >";
                        echo "<input type = 'time'  value= $t->time>";
                        echo "</td >";

                        echo "<td >";
                        echo "<input type = 'time' value=$t->time >";
                        echo "</td >";
}
```

Comment: what did you try ? because is just a loop and a modulo

Comment: Google this: `Php array foreach`

Comment: So basically you haven't tried anything and you're expecting stackoverflow to solve the problem for you...

Comment: @MirzaS I've updated my question with my used code

Comment: code gives understanding that you want time ranges in a specific date, so you need to check your query first,

Comment: what sort of time is this, share your db also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just print the array in the format specified, use the below code.

```
$count=count($time);
for($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++){
    // to display the time in the specified format.
    echo $time[$i]->time.' to '.$time[$i+1]->time."\n";
    // OR you can add your html code to display the time.

}
```

Output:

```
07:30:00 to 08:20:00
08:20:00 to 09:10:00
09:10:00 to 10:00:00
..........
```